# React conditional style with more than 2 cases - smarter way than using a self-invoking function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When I have more than 2 options for conditional style in React, I'd rather not have ternary conditions within ternary conditions, so I use a self-invoking function like this:

```
const HeaderLink = ({
  label,
  linkTo,
  firstItem = false,
  lastItem = false,
}: {
  label: string;
  linkTo: string;
  firstItem?: boolean;
  lastItem?: boolean;
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      id="HeaderLink"
      style={{
        padding: (() => {
          if (firstItem) return "0 1vw 0 0";
          if (lastItem) return "0 0 0 1vw";
          return "0 1vw";
        })(),
      }}
    >
      <Link href={linkTo}>{label}</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It works, but is there a smarter way? Are there reasons to avoid this pattern?

Comment: If you need to pass multiple booleans, that's already a hint of something awry. Why not just pass a string? You're using TypeScript; you can just type it as a union of strings as well. Then you could use a map of strings to classes for your element.

Comment: A more usual way might be to define a string variable "padding" and do the computation before the return statement.  This doesn't "need" to be an IIFE, but it doesn't need to change either.

Answer (score 1):

## You may want to reuse your function

But even if you won't, even in that case you might want to have an easy time reading your code and define the function only once. Instead of a self-invoking function, you may create a function, like

```js
function getWV(firstValue, secondValue) {
    alert("I have been executed");
    //...do your stuff
}

//proof-of-concept
getWV('a', 'b');
```

The example above shows that you can achieve a one-liner in your rendering code, only calling the function instead of defining it each time you render it and obscuring the readability of the renderer.

## You can use helpful arrays

```js
let array = ["0 1vw 0 0", "0 0 0 1vw", "0 1vw"];

function getItem(items)
{
    let filteredArray = items.filter((item) => !!item);
    if (filteredArray.length) return array[items.indexOf(filteredArray[0])];
    return array[items.length];
}

console.log(getItem([null, 3]));
console.log(getItem([null, 0]));
```

At first sight this code may not appear much better than yours, but imagine the case when you may have more than two values. In that case you would have as many `if` conditionals as many items, while the approach above is much more dynamic.